# Mouse wheel event, not working as expected in Firefox, when using Highcharts with PerfectScrollbar

Tags: javascript, highcharts, mouseevent, mousewheel, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using the [highcharts library](https://www.highcharts.com/%20library), it's [related plugins](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and using the [perfect scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar) for scrolling. The chart is extended with plugin for "zooming out" and "zooming in" (on mouse wheel event) and it is placed under the parent `DIV` element (on which the perfect scrollbar is implemented).

Note that this is how it should work:

- when user mouse is hovering the chart and user is scrolling the mouse wheel, the chart is "zoomed out" / "zoomed in" (the events from the highchart plugin is applied);
- if user is not hovering the chart with the mouse and if is scrolling the mouse wheel, then the parent DIV is scrolled down;

The mentioned scenario is already implemented in the following jsfiddle and this works on `Chrome browser`: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/4kh5zbxv/68/

But the problem is that this is not working on `Mozilla Firefox browser`. There, the chart is not "zooming out" / "zooming in" for the cases when user mouse is above the chart;

I'm was not able to detect which one of these two libraries is causing the issue, but the mouse wheel event is somehow included in the issue. I tried many combinations here, but was not able to make it working as expected in the both browsers.

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution based on the *@User863* answer below:
https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/4kh5zbxv/73/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `delta` calculated is always `-1` in `Firefox`

Instead, you can use `deltaY` directly from the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/WheelEvent)

```
let delta = e.deltaY;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/085nvLad/

**Without using perfectScrollbar**

From version 64, firefox having `scrollbar-width`, `scrollbar-color` property. So you can style scrollbar also

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/nf4y3qeh/